# Unable to import SSIS package in SSDT Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I want to import an SSIS package into SSDT Visual Studio 2017 but while doing so I am getting an error i.e. Unable to create the type with name "Azure Storage".(Microsoft.SQlServer.managedDTS). I have installed all the necessary package also in SSIS toolbox Azure content is getting loaded.Please let me know what I am missing.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need install Azure feature package on your server where SSIS reside?

Prerequisites

.Net Framework 4.5

Download the Feature Pack
Download the feature pack from the following locations.

**[Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Integration Services Feature Pack for Azure](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47366)**

Comment: Its not working. I am using  SSDT VS 2017 and SQL Server version is also 2017. 4.5 along with higher version framework is also installed, Feature pack for 2014,2016 and 2017 is also installed. Still  no luck.